# Failing to do rails g bootstrap:install with 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

It seems like I'm having the same issue as the person the OP for:
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/27
but I have not been able to fix it.

Doing a basic rails app like described in:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics
fails with trying to `rails g bootstrap:install`.

The base versions of r/r on my system are:
ruby v 1.9.2p320,
rails 3.1.0
on snow leopard 10.6.4

The way I can replicate on my local system:

```
rails new bsapp --skip-stylesheets
cd bsapp
rails g scaffold product name:string price:decimal --skip-stylesheets
```

add gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' to the assets group in gemfile.

```
bundle update
rails g bootstrap:install
```

This is where the problem is.

```
Hayk-Saakians-Mac:bsapp hayk$ rails g bootstrap:install
/Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:61:in `rescue in lock': uninitialized constant V8::JSError (NameError)
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:60:in `lock'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:19:in `initialize'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:15:in `new'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:15:in `instance'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/loader.rb:10:in `initialize'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less.rb:14:in `new'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less.rb:14:in `<module:Less>'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-rails-2.2.3/lib/less/rails.rb:6:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-rails-2.2.3/lib/less/rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-rails-2.2.3/lib/less-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/less-rails-2.2.3/lib/less-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.3/lib/twitter-bootstrap-rails.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.3/lib/twitter-bootstrap-rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/ror/bsapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/hayk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Hayk-Saakians-Mac:bsapp hayk$
```

full source: http://pastebin.com/nXBcq2bB

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was a bad/old/nonexistent installation of v8/therubyracer/libv8

Certain versions of the libv8 gem just straight up failed to install, and the ones that did -- they took several hours, so I assumed they were hanging/crashing (I am working with a netbook, so that could be expected).

At the moment, the following configuration works for me:

```
gem "libv8", "3.11.8.13"
gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

in development, and in production (heroku)

There was a github issue on either rubyracer or libv8 related to this that mentioned issues with x86/32bit processors -- i don't remember it offhand.